# How can I modify the tumblr bookmarklet to post to a specific tumblr blog?

Tags: javascript, blogs, bookmarklet, tumblr

I have a couple blogs linked to my Tumblr account, but the [bookmarklet](http://www.tumblr.com/goodies) always selects my "primary" blog (the first one in the list).

How can I modify the bookmarklet so that it will auto-select a specific blog?  I would like to have multiple bookmarklet links, e.g. "Share on blog1", "Share on blog2" so that I don't have to manually select which blog to create the post in.

Default Tumblr [bookmarklet](http://www.tumblr.com/goodies) looks like this:

```
javascript: var d = document,
    w = window,
    e = w.getSelection,
    k = d.getSelection,
    x = d.selection,
    s = (e ? e() : (k) ? k() : (x ? x.createRange().text : 0)),
    f = 'http://www.tumblr.com/share',
    l = d.location,
    e = encodeURIComponent,
    p = '?v=3&u=' + e(l.href) + '&t=' + e(d.title) + '&s=' + e(s),
    u = f + p;
try {
    if (!/^(.*\.)?tumblr[^.]*$/.test(l.host)) throw (0);
    tstbklt();
} catch (z) {
    a = function () {
        if (!w.open(u, 't', 'toolbar=0,resizable=0,status=1,width=450,height=430')) l.href = u;
    };
    if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)) setTimeout(a, 0);
    else a();
}
void(0)
```

Comment: Great question. Would love to know the answer.

Comment: Would you be open to using GreaseMonkey scripts in conjunction?

Comment: Does Greasemonkey work on mobile browsers?

Comment: Follow-up for adding tags: [How do I modify the Tumblr Bookmarklet to include a tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18709958/1591669)

Answer (score 1):

Give the bookmarklet a `'channel_id'` post parameter which is `'example_blog_name'` in `example_blog_name.tumblr.com`

```
javascript: var d = document,
    w = window,
    e = w.getSelection,
    k = d.getSelection,
    x = d.selection,
    s = (e ? e() : (k) ? k() : (x ? x.createRange().text : 0)),
    f = 'http://www.tumblr.com/share',
    l = d.location,
    e = encodeURIComponent,
    c = 'example_blog_name',
    p = '?v=3&u=' + e(l.href) + '&t=' + e(d.title) + '&s=' + e(s) + '&channel_id=' + e(c),
    u = f + p;
```

Comment: @trnsfrmr What was the error? What was the query string you passed with your request? "I couldn't get that to work at all" is not very constructive if you are actually trying, in fact, to get it to work.

Comment: I get request denied, see pic: http://imgur.com/TgwtD . @KyleWppd, does it work for you?

Comment: @trnsfrmr Can you paste the request that you are actually sending? Als you will have to be logged in and be able to post to the `channel_id`/example_blog_name to not get the 403.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't logged in. Once logged in to a Tumblr account it will work. Hmmm, I thought the question was asking for something that could handle multiple Tumblr accounts. Having to log and login to switch makes for a very tiresome workflow.

Comment: @jnthnclrk: Not multiple accounts, but multiple blogs (all on the same account).

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of a user script, and a little tweaking to the bookmarklet, here's your solution:

Install this as a [UserScript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/142762):

```
var selectOption = function (elem, value) {
    var options = elem.options;
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        if(options[i].innerHTML === value){
            elem.selectedIndex = i;
        }
    }
};

window.onload = function (){
    if(location.href.indexOf('tumblr.com/share') !== -1){
        selectOption(document.getElementById('channel_id'), location.hash.slice(1));
    }
};
```

Save this as your bookmarklet after editing the `BLOG_NAME` variable. Type it exactly as it is in the dropdown. Also, you'll probably have to run it through [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) to make it a bookmarklet.

```
javascript: var BLOG_NAME = 'Test',
    d = document,
    w = window, 
    e = w.getSelection,
    k = d.getSelection,
    x = d.selection,
    s = (e ? e() : (k) ? k() : (x ? x.createRange().text : 0)),
    f = 'http://www.tumblr.com/share',
    l = d.location,
    e = encodeURIComponent,
    p = '?v=3&u=' + e(l.href) + '&t=' + e(d.title) + '&s=' + e(s),
    u = f + p;
try {
    if (!/^(.*\.)?tumblr[^.]*$/.test(l.host)) throw (0);
    tstbklt();
} catch (z) {
    a = function () {
        if (!w.open(u + '#' + BLOG_NAME, 't', 'toolbar=0,resizable=0,status=1,width=450,height=430')) l.href = u;
    };
    if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)) setTimeout(a, 0);
    else a();
}
void(0);
```